# Asp.net float masked textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation, textbox

I want to make 0-100 float number validation in textbox.
I maked it with 
`<input type=number step=0.1>`

But write 23,25 and save to database. I see 2325  not 23,25.

With asp.net textbox every thing ok. How can i make  a validation or a mask?

Comment: Have you tried using a decimal (`.`) instead of a comma (`,`) in the input field? Example: `23.25`

Comment: yes i tried. but same..

Comment: You have several paths of debugging you need to take. First you should [add min and max validation to the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). Secondly, after entering a value, you should try using JavaScript to tell you the value of the field. If the JavaScript reports the value correctly then there is likely something you need to change on the server.

Comment: _Alternately_, try looking directly at the data that's being sent to your server from the browser. Many browsers have that functionality built in, usually in some kind of "Network" section. To me it sounds like the server is the problem here.